# How should we externalize variables in a Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, scope, vagrant

I have a vagrant file, where I want a variable "servers" to be used ...

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

NUMM = 3
IP_OFFSET = 10
setup_master = File.read("master.sh")
setup_slave = File.read("slave.sh")

def ip_from_num(i)
"172.31.16.#{100+i+IP_OFFSET}"
end

# Map of servers -> parameters. 
servers = {
0 => ["mybox","master.rhbd","ami-759dcb74","ap-northeast-1","subnet-4aa28b22","MASTER",ip_from_num(0)],
1 => ["mybox","slave1.rhbd","ami-759dcb74","ap-northeast-1","subnet-4aa28b22","SLAVE",ip_from_num(1)],
}

def getBox()
   ## this variable isnt available to vagrant...
   servers[0]
end


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  (0..NUMM).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "aws#{i}" do |n|
          n.vm.box = getBox() 
          ...
```

When this Vagrantfile is invoked, however, vagrant complains that the  "servers" variable is not in existence.  This makes sense : If vagrant is invoking from another class, and reading the configuration from that location, then the class variables defined in Vagrantfile might not be accessible in that scope.

So my question is : How can I make variables inside my Vagrantfile accessible to the outside provisioner?  It seems to work okay with function calls (either because they are materialized during creation , or else because vagrant can easily call a function due to default scoping).

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. The code above should work

Comment: Updated with the failing variable (i.e. the variable that isnt accessible by vagrant).

Comment: You can't access a variable from the global scope from insight a method. This is not just related to vagrant but to ruby in general. You need to pass the variable as parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be, to turn the variables into functions - not nice, but if it is good enough for the circumstances:

```
# Map of servers -> parameters. 
def servers()
    {
        0 => ["mybox","master.rhbd","ami-759dcb74","ap-northeast-1","subnet-4aa28b22","MASTER",ip_from_num(0)],
        1 => ["mybox","slave1.rhbd","ami-759dcb74","ap-northeast-1","subnet-4aa28b22","SLAVE",ip_from_num(1)],
    }
end

def getBox()
   ## this variable isnt available to vagrant...
   servers()[0]
end
```

(Assuming `servers` is needed somewhere else too, otherwise it could just be a local variable in `getBox`.)